# Member function not inherited?

Tags: c++

This is my code

```
class B {
public:
  virtual void insert(int t, int p) = 0;

  void insert(int t) {
    insert(t, 0);
  }
};

class D : public B {
public:
  void insert(int t, int p) { }

};

int main() {
  D d;
  d.insert(1);
}
```

which won't compile. Sure, it will if I say d.B::insert(1) in main, but why is this incorrect as is? Thanks.

Comment: See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule

Answer (score 11):

This is because in this case base class functions are not included in overload resolution. Similar situation is with functions declared in inner scope - they do not overload functions declared in outer scope (see examples below). You can imagine that derived class scope is nested inside base class scope.

Once compiler has found `D::insert` candidate it will not look further in base class. If there were no `D::insert` then compiler will look into base class for `insert` method to call. You can fix this by introducing `insert` function names from base class with:

```
using B::insert;
```

this will introduce all the `B::insert` overloaded functions in derived class. Or as you say, you can explicitly call base class method with:

```
d.B::insert(1)
```

---

Sample code to how overloading works in the same way in other contexts:

```
namespace Outer {
  void foo(double d) {
    std::cout << "Outer::foo(double d)\n";
  }
  namespace Inner {  
    //using Outer::foo; // uncomment to see "Outer::foo(double d)" in output
    void foo(int n) {
        std::cout << "Inner::foo(int n)\n";
    }
    void callMe() {
        foo(1.1);
    }
  }   
}

int main() {
    Outer::Inner::callMe(); // Outputes: Inner::foo(int n)
}
```

or:

```
void foo(std::string s) {
    std::cout << "foo(std::string s)\n";
}

void foo(double d) {
    std::cout << "foo(double d)\n";
}

void foo(int n) {
    std::cout << "foo(int n)\n";
}

int main() {
    void foo(int d); // comment out to see foo(double d) in output
    foo(1.1); // outputs: "foo(int n)", foo(double d) is hidden
    //foo("hello"); // ups, it wont compile - name lookup in c++ happens before type checking
                  // commenting out `void foo(int d);` above will fix this.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because you redefined the function "insert" in D, which is the one that gets called. The function "insert" in the class "D" requires two parameters instead of one. By doing d.B::insert(1), you're calling "insert" in B.